# Atributo "required" inválida

Tags: java, xml

Peguei um projeto e o mesmo está apresentando erro de compilação pois não está reconhecendo o atributo "required" no trecho abaixo:

```
@XmlElementRef(name = "Nome", namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/teste/teste/teste", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
```

O erro apresentado é:

> The attribute required is undefined for the annotation type
>   XmlElementRef

Comment: Qual versão do Java você está usando?

Comment: Está configurado no Eclipse 1.6

Answer (score 0):

O problema ocorre porque você está usando o Java 6. O required só passou a ser suportado a partir do Java 7, de acordo com a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementRef.html). Então para funcionar, você vai precisar usar no mínimo o Java 7.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34791197/cannot-find-symbol-method-required-javax-xml-bind-annotation-xmlelementref